# Problems adapting member functions in Phoenix

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I use `BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION` all the time in Spirit. I'd like to be able to adapt member functions for all of the same reason. However, I get compile errors if I do something like this:

```
struct A { int foo(int i) { return 5*i; }};

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(int, AFoo, &A::foo, 2)
```

Is there an easy way to adapt a member function? Note that I can't just store a bind expression in an `auto` because I am on VC2008. How come it doesn't just work like in `bind` and `function`?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(RETURN,LAZY_NAME,FUNC,N)`is really simple. It just creates a functor with a templated `operator()` that returns `RETURN` and has `N` template parameters. In its body it simply invokes `FUNC(PARAMETERS...)`. But `&A::foo` is not directly callable, and so your error occurs. You can use:

```
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(int,AFoo,boost::mem_fn(&A::foo),2)
```

[Running on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a5005c756f54729)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/function.hpp>
#include <boost/mem_fn.hpp>

struct A {
    A(int f) : f_(f) {}

    int foo(int i) {
        return f_*i;
    }
  private: 
    int f_;
};

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(int,AFoo,boost::mem_fn(&A::foo),2)

int main() {
    using namespace boost::phoenix;
    using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;

    A instance(5);
    std::cout << AFoo(arg1,arg2)(&instance, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I know this answer is waaaaaay late, but it may help some future visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the simplest:

> How come it doesn't just work like in bind and function?

Because the macro is designed for functions, not member functions. Pointer-to-member-functions are very different from function pointers, so that's the end of the road.

---

In your example, `A::foo` doesn't actually need to be an *instance method* (non-static member function), so just add `static` (and an implicit parameter) and be done:

```
struct A {
    static int foo(int i) {
        return 5*i;
    }
};

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(int, AFoo, A::foo, 1)
```

---

Let's assume, though, that you *did* want to have the non-static member function. For this reason, let's add a little state to the `A` type:

```
struct A {
    A(int f) : f_(f) {}
    int foo(int i) { return f_*i; }
  private: 
    int f_;
};
```

Phoenix provides the following approaches to create lazy actors calling member functions:

0. use the `->*` operator. This leads to slightly obscure syntax:

   ```
   A instance(9);

   int direct    = (arg1->*&A::foo)(arg2)
                       (&instance, 7); // direct == 63
   ```
1. alternatively, you can use a `bind` expression (note: `boost::phoenix::bind` here!), which might just be what you were looking for:

   ```
   int with_bind = bind(&A::foo, arg1, arg2)
                       (&instance, 7);
   ```

Now, of course, you might be looking to assign the lazy functor to a variable. In that respect, I can only recommend `BOOST_AUTO`:

```
BOOST_AUTO(afoo, (arg1->*&A::foo)(arg2));
return afoo(&instance, 2);
```

Which works like a charm.

#### Full C++03 Sample

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/114597ad8ca0239c)**

```
struct A {
    A(int f) : f_(f) {}

    int foo(int i) {
        return f_*i;
    }
  private: 
    int f_;
};

#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/function.hpp>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::phoenix;
    using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;

    A instance(9);

    int direct    = (arg1->*&A::foo)(arg2)
                        (&instance, 7);

    int with_bind = bind(&A::foo, arg1, arg2)
                        (&instance, 7);

    assert(direct == with_bind);

    BOOST_AUTO(afoo, (arg1->*&A::foo)(arg2));

    return afoo(&instance, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it is what I was afraid of. The only one of these that seems to work for me on my programs VS2008  is the bind solution, which is what I had been using and hoping for something better (due to nested templates, there is some wonky context). Oh well, it's good to know at least.